# OpenCL - Vectorization vs In-thread for loop

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl

I have a problem where I need to process a known number of threads in parallel (great), but for which each thread may have a vastly different number of internal iterations (not great). In my mind, this makes it better to do a kernel scheme like this:

```
__kernel something(whatever)
{
   unsigned int glIDx = get_global_id(0);

   for(condition_from_whatever)
   {

   }//alternatively, do while

}
```

where id(0) is known beforehand, rather than:

```
__kernel something(whatever)
{
   unsigned int glIDx = get_global_id(0);
   unsigned int glIDy = get_global_id(1); // max "unroll dimension"

   if( glIDy_meets_condition)
      do_something();
   else
      dont_do_anything();

}
```

which would necessarily execute for the FULL POSSIBLE RANGE of glIDy, with no way to terminate beforehand, as per this discussion:

[Killing OpenCL Kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308667/killing-opencl-kernels)

I can't seem to find any specific information about costs of dynamic-sized forloops / do-while statements within kernels, though I do see them everywhere in kernels in Nvidia's and AMD's SDK. I remember reading something about how the more aperiodic an intra-kernel condition branch is, the worse the performance.

ACTUAL QUESTION:

Is there a more efficient way to deal with this on a GPU architecture than the first scheme I proposed?

I'm also open to general information about this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the x dimension gives you enough parallelism, your approach of looping over the variably-sized dimension should be fine.  Note that the overall kernel time will be dictated by the longest-running loop.  This may be fine if you can generate enough threads or if you have other concurrent kernels that can start using resources freed from fast thread groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a general answer that can be given to that question. It really depends on your problem.

However here are some considerations about this topic:

for loop / if else statements may or may not have an impact to the performance of a kernel. The fact is the performance cost is not at the kernel level but at the work-group level. A work-group is composed of one or more warps (NVIDIA)/ wavefront (AMD). These warps (I'll keep the NVIDIA terminology but it's exactly the same for AMD) are executed in lock-step.

So if within a warp you have divergence because of an if else (or a for loop with different iterations number) the execution will be serialized. That is to say that the threads within this warp following the first path will do their jobs will the others will idle. Once their job is finished, these threads will idle while the others will start working.

Another problem arise with these statements if you need to synchronize your threads with a barrier. You'll have an undefined behavior if not all the threads hit the barrier.

Now, knowing that and depending on your specific problem, you might be able to group your threads in such a fashion that within the work-groups there is not divergence, though you'll have divergence between work-groups (no impact there).

Knowing also that a warp is composed of 32 threads and a wavefront of 64 (maybe not on old AMD GPUs - not sure) you could make the size of your well organized work-groups equal or a multiple of these numbers. Note that it is quite simplified because some other problems should be taken into consideration. See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866935/why-is-preferred-work-group-size-multiple-part-of-kernel-properties/15964724#15964724) and the answer given by Chanakya.sun (maybe more digging on that topic would be nice).

In the case your problem could not be organized as just described, I'd suggest to consider using OpenCL on CPUs which are quite good dealing with branching. If I well recall, typically you'll have one work-item per work-group. In that case, better to check the documentation from Intel and AMD for CPU. I also like very much the chapter 6 of [Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL](http://developer.amd.com/partners/university-programs/heterogeneous-computing-with-opencl/) which explains the differences between using OCL with GPUs and CPUs when programming.

I like [this article](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/) too. It's mainly a discussion about increasing performance for a simple reduction on GPU (not your problem), but the last part of the article examines also performance on CPUs.

Last thing, regarding your comments on the answer provided by @Oak about the "intra-device thread queuing support" which is actually called dynamic parallelism. This feature would obviously solve your problem but even using CUDA you'd need a device with capability 3.5 or higher. So even NVIDIA GPUs with Kepler GK104 architecture don't support it (capability 3.0). For OCL, the dynamic parallelism is part of the standard version 2.0. (as far as I know there is no implementation yet).

Comment: Thanks, I think this was as close to an answer as I was looking for.  I guess next gen it doesn't matter as much with the introduction of DP. Also, I feel like there needs to be a more prevalent "APU" card for PCI-E, like one of those 72 core intel that are coming out, but w/o North/southbridge/SATA etc, and just PCIE and DDR3/4 interface. That way one can select between GPU, APU, regular CPU, depending on problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like the 2nd version more, since `for` inserts a false dependency between iterations. If the inner iterations are independent, send each to a different work item and let the OpenCL implementation sort out how best to run them.

Two caveats:

- If the average number of iterations is significantly lower than the max number of iterations, this might not be worth the extra dummy work items.
- You will have a lot more work items and you still need to calculate the condition for each... if calculating the condition is complicated this might not be a good idea.

  - Alternatively, you can flatten the indices into the x dimension, group all the iterations into the same work-group, then calculate the condition just once per workgroup and use local memory + barriers to sync it.

Comment: Well, I think the general strategy to these problems, that I have found, and that others seem to use in various open-source software I've seen, is to have a host-side thread management suite and to efficiently break up the computation into smaller sets of iterations and check whether threads have terminated in between. Problems with this include a ton of host-device IO. To me, the difference between the two I listed is that the 1st scheme would probably waste less power than the 2nd scheme. I honestly posted with this fully expecting a bunch of examples.

Comment: I did see in an NVIDIA slideshow for kepler, that there is intra-device thread queuing support, (one thread can queue another thread), which, unless I'm missing something, effectively solves this problem. But I don't think thats made it into AMD hardware, (or if it will anytime soon), so the chances of seeing support in an upcoming OCL release is probably slim to none.

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf